# Force to align left a empheq box

Tags: empheq

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{empheq}

\definecolor{lightgrey}{HTML}{f0f0f0}

\newtcbox{\resultbox}[1][lightgrey]{
    nobeforeafter,
    math upper, 
    tcbox raise base,
    enhanced, 
    boxrule=1pt,
    colback = #1!30,
    drop lifted shadow, 
    sharp corners
}


\begin{document}

    \begin{empheq}[box=\resultbox]{equation*}
        a(t) = 2\alpha - \gamma\omega^2 cos(\omega t)
    \end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

result:

[image]

there any way to force align to left  of that `empheq` box?

Thank you.

---

EDIT: sorry for the inconvenience, from now it's already full minimum code to be compiled.

is there any way to use `fleqn` to only affects the class `\resultbox`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to add the option `fleqn` to your document class line.

[image]

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,theorems}
\usepackage{empheq}
\newtcbox{\resultbox}[1][lightgray]{
    nobeforeafter,
    math upper,
    tcbox raise base,
    enhanced,
    boxrule=1pt,
    colback = #1!30,
    drop lifted shadow,
    sharp corners
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{empheq}[box=\resultbox]{equation*}
        v(t) = 2\alpha t - \gamma\omega sen(\omega t))
    \end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

Next time please give a full [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228). In particular, the code should compile.

**EDIT to typeset equation on the left without setting fleqn globally**

The `fleqn` option sets a flag `@fleqn` that is used by the [empheq](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/empheq) package to typeset the equation on left. The hack below sets this flag when the package is loaded and then creates a new environment `Empheq` that sets this flag for the environment only. With this in place, you can have your cake and eat it too, so to speak.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,theorems}
\newtcbox{\resultbox}[1][lightgray]{
    nobeforeafter,
    math upper,
    tcbox raise base,
    enhanced,
    boxrule=1pt,
    colback = #1!30,
    drop lifted shadow,
    sharp corners
}
\makeatletter% hack to allow empheq environment to be used with fleqn in force only locally
\@fleqntrue
\usepackage{empheq}
\newenvironment{Empheq}{\@fleqntrue\empheq[box=\resultbox]{equation*}}{\endempheq}
\@fleqnfalse
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \begin{Empheq}
        v(t) = 2\alpha t - \gamma\omega sen(\omega t))
    \end{Empheq}
    \begin{equation*}
        v(t) = 2\alpha t - \gamma\omega sen(\omega t))
    \end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

I have typeset the equation normally underneath to highlight the difference. I have not tested this hack comprehensively. It is unlikely that it breaks something else as this is not the way the `fleqn` is meant to be used. In particular, other `empheq` environments in your document will almost certainly be broken.

Comment: is there any way to use fleqn to only affects the class \resultbox without affects the rest of equations? Thank you!

Comment: See my edit for a hack.