# How can I place an array in empheq environment?

Tags: arrays, empheq

I'd like to place an array in a empheq environment. I tried the following code which gives the error: Paragraph ended before \empheq was complete.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}
\begin{empheq}[box={\mymath[colback=Bittersweet!20]}]{equation}
\vec{a}\times \vec{b}=\left|
\begin{array}{c c c}

\ii & \jj & \kk \\
a_x & a_y & a_z \\
b_x & b_y & b_z \\

\end{array}
\right|
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your minimal working example does not compile because `\ii`, `\jj`, `\kk`, `\vec` and `\mymath` are not defined. I think the empty lines inside the `array` are likely the problem though.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! A blank line introduces a new paragraph, whence the error message. Unrelated: it is simpler to replace your `array`  construction with `\begin{vmatrix} ... \end{vmatrix}`, defined by `amsmath` (which `empheq` loads).

Answer (score 1):

While blank lines are not illegal in an `array` environment, generally, they are inside the display environments defined by `amsmath` such as `align` or `gather`. Also `empheq` doesn't accept them.

In these cases the blank lines are caught *before* `array` can deal with them.

The solution is

> ***never use blank lines in math mode***.

Here I made up definitions for `\ii`, `\jj` and `\kk` and also copied one for `\mybox` [from an example in the site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/325499/4427). In future questions, please provide these details and make your example codes compilable.

I also used `vmatrix` instead of `array`, because it makes for better spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\newcommand{\ii}{\vec{\imath}}
\newcommand{\jj}{\vec{\jmath}}
\newcommand{\kk}{\vec{k}}

\newtcbox{\mymath}[1][]{
    nobeforeafter,
    math upper, 
    tcbox raise base,
    enhanced, 
    boxrule=1pt,
    drop lifted shadow, 
    sharp corners,
    #1,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[box={\mymath[colback=Bittersweet!20]}]{equation}
\vec{a}\times \vec{b}=
\begin{vmatrix}
\ii & \jj & \kk \\
a_x & a_y & a_z \\
b_x & b_y & b_z \\
\end{vmatrix}
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It’s exactly what I wanted. I’m sorry that I forgot to define the unit vectors. It was my first question.

Comment: @DimitriosSykias Don't worry and be very welcome!