# Left align empheq fbox

Tags: alignment, empheq

I am trying to figure out the syntax for generating a set of left-aligned, boxed equations with aligned equals signs for presenting some results. After trying many combinations of methods, this is the closest I've gotten:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{empheq}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{6pt}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{itemize}
        \item[1a.]
            here's some text
            
            $some=math$
            
            \begin{empheq}[box=\fbox]{align*}
                R_{b1} &= 12\Omega\\
                R_{b2} &= 123\Omega\\
                R_c &= 1234\Omega\\
                R_{ee} &= 12345\Omega
            \end{empheq}
            
    \end{itemize}
    
\end{document}
```

This results in the following (colored lines and arrow added).
[image: not left aligned box]

I would like to left align the box as shown so it fits with the rest of the text on the page. I found [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/325499/force-to-align-left-a-empheq-box), which suggests adding `fleqn` to `\documentclass`. However, this still leaves the box floating an odd distance away from the bottom and left edges of the preceding text.

[image: odd margin]

How can I left align my box without this weird space?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ... syntax for generating a set of left-aligned, boxed equations with aligned equals signs

I would like to suggest that you load the `amsmath` package and employ its `boxed` macro and `aligned` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{6pt} % default: 3pt

\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Hello world. 
            
              $\boxed{\begin{aligned}
                R_{b1} &= 12\Omega    \\
                R_{b2} &= 123\Omega   \\
                R_c    &= 1234\Omega  \\
                R_{ee} &= 12345\Omega
              \end{aligned}}$
    \end{enumerate}   
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1, perhaps it would encourage the OP to use the siunitx package for writing of quantities: `R_{b1} &= \qty{12}{\ohm}` ;-)`

Comment: @Zarkoi - Thanks! :-). At one point, while I was writing this answer, I did think about adding some thoughts regarding the typesetting of scientific quantities with the help of the machinery of the `siunitx` package. But then I decided against it, because I judged that it would address a point that’s related only tangentially to the OP’s query.